# Are Associate Links in an iOS App against the App Store Review Guidelines?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, in-app-purchase, links

Our iOS app is a (free) utility app that offers a kind of "private" social network for tennis clubs.

For monetization purposes, we have considered adding Amazon affiliate links in a native way to the app, i.e. not showing banners but instead adding helpful links triggered by native buttons in the app.
*Example*: When creating a tennis court booking, we have a button that says "Already bought tennis balls? We recommend: **[button that triggers an affiliate link]**".

However, in section 3.1.1 (In-App Purchase) of the App Store it says:

> If you want to unlock features or functionality within your app, [..], you must use in-app purchase. [..] Apps and their metadata **may not include buttons, external links, or other calls to action that direct customers to purchasing mechanisms other than in-app purchase**.

(emphasis mine)

Does the above scenario violate the App Store Review Guidelines in this or another section?

Comment: I think that this should be fine. The purchase is not for the app/in-app (you're not buying tennis balls to be used in the app). Especially due to the amount of ads in apps today that on a tap will open a page to purchase.